# python Regex match exact word

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match different expressions for addresses:

Example:  '398 W. Broadway'

I would like to match W. or E. (east) or Pl. for place ...etc

It is very simple using this regex

`(W.|West)` for example.

Yet python re module doesn't match anything when I input that

```
>>> a
'398 W. Broadway'
>>> x = re.match('(W.|West)', a)
>>> x
>>> x == None
True
>>>
```

Comment: `.` has special meaning in regular expressions.

Comment: Off topic, but `x == None` will not give what you expect in all situations because `False == None` is `True`, as is `0 == None`, `[] == None`, and `'' == None`.  To check if something is `None` and not just `False`, use `x is None`.

Comment: thank you for that. Yes I never do `==None` in code, this is just the shell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) matches at the beginning of the input string.

To match anywhere, use [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('a', 'abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000001E18578>
>>> re.match('a', 'bac')
>>> re.search('a', 'bac')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002654370>
```

See [`search() vs. match()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match):

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular
>   expressions: re.match() checks for a match only at the beginning of
>   the string, while re.search() checks for a match anywhere in the
>   string (this is what Perl does by default).

Comment: what if I want to substitute it? I tried using sub() but it didnt work

Comment: @Saher, How did you used `sub`?  You should use as `re.sub(old_pattern, replacement_string_or_function, target_string)`. See [`re.sub` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

Comment: @Saher, Use raw string (`r'(W\.|West)'`) if possible.

Answer (score 3):

`.match()` constrains the search to begin at the first character of the string.  Use `.search()` instead.  Note too that `.` matches any character (except a newline).  If you want to match a literal period, escape it (`\.` instead of plain `.`).